# Tailwind CSS Not Building Correctly When Next.js App Started via Node.js Script

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, next.js, tailwind-css

I'm working on a project with a Next.js frontend located in a client directory and a Node.js backend in a server directory. The project structure looks something like this:

```
jukerabbit/
├─ client/
│  ├─ pages/
│  ├─ components/
│  ├─ tailwind.config.ts
│  └─ ...
└─ server/
   ├─ server.ts
   └─ ...
```

I'm starting my Next.js application from a Node.js script located in the server directory (`server/server.ts`). When I start the Next app directly from the client directory using `next dev`, Tailwind CSS works perfectly, and my styles are applied as expected.

However, when I start the Next.js app through my Node.js script, I receive warnings indicating that Tailwind can't find my content sources:

```
warn - The `content` option in your Tailwind CSS configuration is missing or empty.
warn - Configure your content sources or your generated CSS will be missing styles.
warn - https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration
```

Here's a simplified version of how I'm starting the Next app from my `server.ts`:

```
const express = require('express');
const next = require('next');
const path = require('path');

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const app = next({ dev, dir: path.join(__dirname, '../client') });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

app.prepare().then(() => {
  const server = express();

  server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    return handle(req, res);
  });

  const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
  server.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`> Ready on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
  });
});
```

And here's my `tailwind.config.ts` in the client directory:

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  // other Tailwind config...
};
```

I suspect the issue is related to how paths are resolved when the Next app is started from the server directory, but I'm unsure how to fix this. I actually did find the warning was suppressed by changing the content path to just `./**.*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}`, but it still didn't build the css.

I realize starting a Next server through Node like this is slightly unorthodox, so I'm having trouble finding relevant threads. Actually launching Next works fine -- I'm just stuck on getting Tailwind to build. Any insight would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your `tailwind.config.ts` is expecting the content paths to be relative to the current working directory, which is the `client` directory when you run `next dev` directly. However, when you start the app from the `server` directory, the current working directory changes, and the paths in your Tailwind config no longer point to the correct locations.

You can use Node.js's `__dirname` global variable, which gives you the directory name of the current module, to build an absolute path to your content files.

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  content: [
    path.join(__dirname, 'pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}'),
    path.join(__dirname, 'components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}'),
  ],
  // other Tailwind config...
};
```